# Terraform how to modify an arn for a resource?

Tags: terraform

I am using data to get the snapshot for a cluster.

```
data "aws_db_cluster_snapshot" "db" {
  for_each               = toset(var.rds_sources)
  db_cluster_identifier  = each.key
  most_recent            = true
}
```

and i am using it like :-

```
jsonencode(values(data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.db)[*].db_cluster_snapshot_arn)
```

and it return the snapshot in the following format :-

```
arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:916533587194:cluster-snapshot:rds:new-test-db-2022-09-12-08-05
```

How can i modify the arn to be in the following format :-

```
arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:916533587194:cluster-snapshot:rds:new-test-db*
```

Comment: Is the string `new-test-db-` constant, or you have general form of <some-string>-<some-date>?

Comment: @Marcin Great question. It's a general form of `<some-string>-<some-date>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [replace](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/replace) with a regex pattern:

```
replace(jsonencode(values(data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.db)[*].db_cluster_snapshot_arn),"/-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/","*")
```